# Enable Dynamic price in bundle product

Tags: bundled-product, magento2.4, bundle, bundle-product, dynamic-price

I want a fixed price in my bundle product. According to the Magento [official documentation](https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/catalog/product-create-bundle.html) I have to set "Dynamic Price" to yes and then change the Price input. The problem is that the Dynamic Price input is disabled and I don´t know the proper way to change it.

[image]

What I try is update the value in the table "catalog_product_entity_int" where the attribute_id was equal to "130 (dynamic price id)" and the entity_id equal to my product id. With this update I could add a fixed price but I know there should be a better way.

All of this is in a new magento 2.4.0 installation

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the documentation could be more specific. Only when creating a new product can you determine if it is dynamic pricing or not. Once the product is created, it cannot be modified.